# Autolayout put UIView in the middle between the margin and another UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

i want know how i can put a UIView in the middle between the margin of the screen and another UIView using auto layout in interface builder, this is the schema:

```
 margin| --UIViewTocenter-- |UIView
```

`margin` is the left margin of the superview, then to the right there is the `UIView`, and i want put the `UIViewToCenter` in the middle between the two elements, how i can do it in interface builder?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to put an extra container view. So you will have something like that:

```
|-margin-[ContinerView]-|[UIView]|
```

And then inside ContainerView put your UIViewToCenter and center it in its superview.

```
|-UIViewToCenter-|
```